# Run PsExec with relative

Tags: powershell, path, psexec

I try to run a script on a remote computer with PsExec.

```
C:\static\path\to\thePSTools\Folder\PsTools\PsExec.exe $IPAddress -i -s -u $Login -p $LoginPassword Powershell $PathToFile
```

But I just can run the the PsExec Command when writing like the code above, meaning, running PsExec from an absolute Path.

The thing is when my Program is installed on another machine, then I don't know the static path of my PsExec. So I need a relative Path.
I tried a few things but none of it worked

Like this with Push-Location:

```
Push-Location $PSToolsPath PsExec.exe $IPAddress /accepteula $PathToFile
```

Or something like this:

```
$Path + PsExec.exe $IPAddress /accepteula $PathToFile
```

But I can't run it.

I know how to get the relative Path, but the question is, how to run, or is it even possible.

I am open for any edit on my question. Since its kind of complicated to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `PSExec`. While useful, `PSExec` is a CLI program for running commands over `WinRM`. PowerShell already has `PSRemoting` built in (`WinRM` is the backbone of `PSRemoting`) and you can use `New-PSSession`, `Enter-PSSession`, `Invoke-Command`, etc. in order to access remote machines you control access to:

> **Note:** You must use a server name to connect to the server by default. If the server is not part of your domain or you want to use an IP, you must configure your local `WinRM` settings to trust that IP or server name. Alternatively, you can configure `WinRM over SSL` to avoid having to trust servers by IP, but your client server will need to both trust the certificate presented by `WinRM over SSL`, and the **Subject** or **Subject-Alternative Name** of the certificate must validate based on the name or IP you connect with.
>
> `WinRM` and `PSRemoting` do not allow you to ignore SSL errors.

```
# Your remote machine credential
$cred = Get-Credential

# Run commands in a one off remote session
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $cred { "hello" }

# Create a PSSession so we can run commands over the same session at different times
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $cred

# Invoke-Command with an existing PSSession
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $cred -Session $session { "hello" }

# Enter-PSSession lets you open an interactive terminal within a remote PowerShell session
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $cred -Session $session

# To leave a PSSession you've entered with Enter-PSSession
Exit-PSSession
exit
```

Note that `exit` is not an alias of `Exit-PSSession`, it just has the same effect when you exit the remote session as when you exit a local session.

---

If you must use `PSExec` (for example, `PSRemoting` doesn't let you run stuff as the `SYSTEM` user directly, but `PSExec` does), then one of two things must be true to execute `psexec.exe`:

> The following is not just true for `PSExec`, but for any program run on Windows, MacOS, or Windows due to their Unix roots or influences. Each one shares the `PATH` concept, and without this, you must know where the program exists on disk or "you ain't runnin' it".

- `psexec.exe` must exist in one of the directories defined `$env:PATH`
- You must know the absolute or relative path from your current directory to `psexec.exe`

  - What you are calling a "static path" is actually called the "absolute path", which starts from the drive root such as `C:\path\to\psexec.exe`.
  - A relative path would be the path from your current directory, **without** starting at the drive root such as `..\..\path\to\psexec.exe`.

If you don't know where the program is installed and it's not on the `PATH`, your only other option is to copy from media or download it where you know it will be stored on disk.

---

### Well... I lied a bit

There is one way you can locate `psexec.exe` (or another program) if you are certain it exists on the system. You can search the filesystem for it. The more files you have and the lower your IOPS are will extend the time it takes for the search to complete. If you find the executable, you can execute it with the call operator `&`:

> **Warning:** *Be careful with this approach*. If multiple executables exist which have the same name but are different versions or different programs entirely, you could accidentally end up executing the wrong version, wrong program altogether, or worst-case scenario, a malicious actor could place a modified or fake `psexec.exe` designed to steal your credentials or otherwise cause damage to your environment. **You have been warned**.
>
> If you go this route, check the known checksum of the program you search for. The below example does not include this but you can use `Get-FileHash` to obtain a found `psexec.exe`'s checksum, and compare it to the known correct checksum.

```
$foundPsExec = Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse -File -Include psexec.exe -EA Continue |
  Select-Object -First 1

if( $foundPsExec ) {
  & $foundPsExec.FullName
}
```

Allow me to explain a few things from the above example:

- `Get-ChildItem` will search the filesystem for files at the path you provide.

  - `-Recurse` will allow `Get-ChildItem` to traverse child directories while searching.
  - `-File` only returns `FileInfo` objects
  - `-EA` is shorthand for `-ErrorAction`. We want to ensure this behavior is set to continue on this operation because when searching the entire disk you are bound to hit some permissions errors.

    You can hide them instead with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or have PowerShell throw any errors away altogether with `-ErrorAction Ignore`.
- This uses `Select-Object` to only assign the first instance of `PSExec` to the variable. You should implement some safer checks if you use this solution, I have only provided this as an example of making sure you only use one path when executing with `&`.
- If `$foundPsExec` has a value, run it with the absolute path (this is referenced with `FileInfo.FullName`, hence the `FullName` property reference.

Comment: Thank you for you long answer :) Yeah i meant absolute and relative path, i translated it wrong it seems. 
The Invoke-Command and PsSession, doesn't work in our Workgroup, thats why im using PsExec

Comment: No worries, it happens. Best part is now you know. "And knowing is half the battle!"

Comment: i changed the dynamic and static in my question, to relative and absolute. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include one more thing you can do but I don't recommend it unless you know its checksum and can validate it. I did not include that here as the answer already became quite long :D

Comment: Thanks, i found that solution with the '&' operator about 5 minutes ago and it does the trick :)